# sparklyr: create new column with mutate function

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr

I'm very surprised if this kind of problems cannot be solved with sparklyr:

```
iris_tbl <- copy_to(sc, aDataFrame)

# date_vector is a character vector of element
# in this format: YYYY-MM-DD (year, month, day)
for (d in date_vector) {
   ...
   aDataFrame %>% mutate(newValue=gsub("-","",d)))
   ...
}
```

I receive this error:

```
Error: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Undefined function: 'GSUB'. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database 'default'.; line 2 pos 86
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.failFunctionLookup(SessionCatalog.scala:787)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionCatalog.lookupFunction0(HiveSessionCatalog.scala:200)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionCatalog.lookupFunction(HiveSessionCatalog.scala:172)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveFunctions$$anonfun$apply$13$$anonfun$applyOrElse$6$$anonfun$applyOrElse$39.apply(Analyzer.scala:884)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveFunctions$$anonfun$apply$13$$anonfun$applyOrElse$6$$anonfun$applyOrElse$39.apply(Analyzer.scala:884)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$.withPosition(package.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveFunctions$$anonfun$apply$13$$anonfun
```

But with this line:

```
aDataFrame %>% mutate(newValue=toupper("hello"))
```

things work. Some help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would strongly recommend you read the `sparklyr` documentation before proceeding.  In particular, you're going to want to read the section on how R is translated to SQL (http://spark.rstudio.com/dplyr.html#sql_translation).  In short, a very limited subset of R functions are available for use on `sparklyr` dataframes, and `gsub` is not one of those functions (but `toupper` is). If you really need `gsub` you're going to have to `collect` the data in to a local dataframe, then `gsub` it (you can still use `mutate`), then `copy_to` back to spark.

Answer (score 11):

It may be worth adding that the available documentation states:

> ### Hive Functions
>
> Many of Hive’s built-in functions (UDF) and built-in aggregate functions (UDAF) can be called inside dplyr’s mutate and summarize. The [Languange Reference UDF](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-StringOperators) page provides the list of available functions.

## Hive

As stated in the documentation, a viable solution should be achievable with use of [**`regexp_replace`**](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-StringOperators):

> Returns the string resulting from replacing all substrings in
>   `INITIAL_STRING` that match the java regular expression syntax defined
>   in `PATTERN` with instances of `REPLACEMENT.` For example,
>   `regexp_replace("foobar", "oo|ar", "")` returns `'fb.'` Note that some
>   care is necessary in using predefined character classes: using `'\s'` as
>   the second argument will match the letter `s; '\\s'` is necessary to
>   match whitespace, etc.

## `sparklyr` approach

Considering the above it should be possible to combine `sparklyr` pipeline with 
`regexp_replace` to achieve effect cognate to applying `gsub` on the desired column. Tested code removing the **`-`** character within `sparklyr` in variable **`d`** could be build as follows:

```
aDataFrame %>% 
  mutate(clnD = regexp_replace(d, "-", "")) %>%
  # ...
```

*where `class(aDataFrame )` returns: `"tbl_spark" ...`.*

Comment: Is regexp_replace a sparkrlyr function? I can only find it in SparkR.

Comment: @dalloliogm [`regexp_replace`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF) it's a Hive function as the provided solution uses Hive's function.